# How can I set the user info line in eggdrop?

Tags: irc, bots

I have installed [eggdrop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggdrop) to a IRC channel. I have enabled greeting the user by setting the +greet option in eggdrop.conf. Apparently, however, a "user info line" (http://www.egghelp.org/faq.htm#104) has to be added for each user (which contains the actual greeting). How can this be done - I found no documentation of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the `.chinfo` command:

```
###  chinfo  [channel] [info-line/none]
   Sets the information line for a user. This line is shown via the /msg
   commands 'who' and 'whois'. If you have set greet on, it is also
   shown when the user joins the channel. If the info line begins with an '@',
   then it is "locked", and that user may no longer change it. If the channel
   name is omitted, the default info line is changed. If you specify 'none'
   as the info-line, it will be erased.
```